# Text figures in latex figures, tables and references

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats, cross-referencing, text

I'm searching for a way to enforce [text figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures) in LaTeX tables, figures, and the references (and cross-referencing) to tables and figures.

For instance, the table number should be written with `text figure` format.

Please let me know if something is not clear. Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: try  `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\oldstylenums{\arabic{figure}}}` for example

Comment: Added comment to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}

%---------------------
% just for the example
\usepackage{mwe}
\setcounter{figure}{18}
\setcounter{table}{68}
%---------------------

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\oldstylenums{\arabic{figure}}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\oldstylenums{\arabic{table}}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

my nice figure \ref{nf} and  my table \ref{nt}\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.45]{example-image}
\caption{Nice  figure}
\label{nf}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{Nice table}\label{nt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
a & 1 \\ 
\hline 
b & 2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Update** if chapters used

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{%
\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \oldstylenums{\arabic{chapter}}.\fi
\oldstylenums{\arabic{figure}}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{%
\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \oldstylenums{\arabic{chapter}}.\fi\oldstylenums{\arabic{table}}}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great if you are referring to a figure in a section.. not when the figure is in a given section of a chapter.

Comment: @tandem answer updated.

Comment: thanks for the update. but now there is an error.. here it is: `Package textcomp Warning: Oldstyle digits unavailable for family ptm.
(textcomp)                Lining digits used instead on input line 102.`

Comment: @tandem you didn't provide a minimal example so  i can't guess what fonts and packages are used.

Comment: This is the template I'm using. https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template

Comment: @tandem add to your preambl `\renewcommand{\oldstylenums}[1]{{\fontfamily{pplj}\selectfont #1}}` or `\renewcommand{\oldstylenums}[1]{{\fontencoding{OML}\selectfont #1}}` I don't know which one look better

Comment: I doesn't seem to help. could you tell me what exactly it does, and I will try to work through it.

Comment: I guess there is another package I am using currently that is conflicting..need to check with original template

Comment: @tandem i'll try to see later, what is your compiler? pdflatex?

Comment: Yes, it is `pdflatex`

Comment: Please let me know if you have something on this

Comment: @tandem I just tried `\renewcommand{\oldstylenums}[1]{{\fontfamily{pplj}\selectfon‌​t #1}}` as suggested above and it works perfectly.

Comment: Let me check again.. maybe I am missing something then.

Comment: @Johannes_B: is that all you added to the preamble of the template? I cloned again, and tried with it and had no luck. Plus I got the following error message: `Package textcomp Warning: Oldstyle digits unavailable for family ptm.
(textcomp)                Lining digits used instead on input line 104.`

Comment: @tandem I copied the short block that has the *Update* above (answer) and the line mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: That explains. I was using just the update, and it didn't make much sense :-) Thanks!

Comment: Just another question: How do I add this feature also to section references? for instance to this.. `Section~\ref{sec: foobarbaz}`

Comment: you need to redefine `\thesection` in the same way you do with `\thefigure`.